# Searching substring in a row of mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have column name `code_color` which have combination of number and letters like `009grey` 
so the problem is I am asking a user for color only which is `grey` so how do I search only the color string? 
here is the query

```
 "SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE name = '$searchKeyword' AND code_color = '$color' AND sex = '$gender' ";
```

where `code_color` have the strings like that `009grey`, `008red` etc and color from user would be `grey` or any other color. How can I do it ?

#### Edit

What if it is stored in DB as `m` and we get from user is $_POST['sex'] which contains `male` how can we search for it ? LIKE %% methods doesn't seems to apply here !

Comment: Sounds like a use for a regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"SELECT * 
FROM shoes WHERE name = '$searchKeyword' 
AND code_color LIKE '%$color%' 
AND sex = '$gender' ";
```

Your code is open to injections however, you should look into using parameterized queries. (Using MySQLi or PDO)

Comment: What if in DB it is `m` and getting from user is `male` in super-global variable `$_POST['sex']` I cant do `m%ale` in that case because its a variable

Comment: Why `m%ale`, that doesn't even make sense. You can use `%` at the beginning or end of the string or both. What you're asking now is a very different question than you originally asked.

Comment: no offense I am trying to learn.. after solving the question i asked i had this problem so i thought it would be same or somehow around it

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE code_colour LIKE '%$color'
```

keep in mind if you are pasting variables directly into your SQL query you are vulnerable to SQL Injection - http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Comment: edited the question can you please have a look at this one now ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to skip the first three digits of `code_color` before attempting the search

```
SELECT * 
FROM shoes 
WHERE name = :kw AND SUBSTRING(code_color, 4) = :color AND sex = :gender
```

*The `:<name>` notation is used to denote parameter placeholders as those used in prepared statements.*

Answer (score 0):

Remove all numbers from string with regex

```
$color = preg_replace('/[^\\/\-a-z\s]/i', '', $color);
"SELECT * 
FROM shoes WHERE name = '$searchKeyword' 
AND code_color ='$color' 
AND sex = '$gender' ";
```